# Drop Table does not free all the space

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

We have a daily process that creates a large innodb table and drops the table created two days before. The table is roughly 20G of data and another 20G of index. The storage usage graph shows:

Day 25 88G then a spike to 120G during the processing
Day 26 106G then a spike to 139G during the processing
Day 27 124G then a spike to 157G during the processing
Day 28 142G

The problem is 18G is NOT being freed in the table drop.

`select @@innodb_file_per_table` results 1, which I interpret it as ON

What can be done to prevent the 20G a day in unused space wastage?  I suspect there is a billing impact?

Comment: Are you sure this is connected? According to that documentation, during the first 25 days you haven't used 18 GB per day

Comment: The 25 is May 25.  We started the process on May 21.

Comment: Check what is taking that space usage, maybe it is not the table itself, it might be temporal data or binary logs

Answer (score 0):

These could be your CloudSQL backups. The [automated backups](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#automated-backups) backup data every four hours automatically. You can check if that's what it is. Temporal data would be gone if you restart, so we can try that as well to eliminate that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the extra 18G per day was the transaction logs that where retained for 7 days.  So after peaking at 200G after 7 days, for some reason it settled into a pattern of 140G during the day and peaking to 160G when the next day's data set is processes and old one dropped.